# Now that Star Wars is coming out on Blu-Ray, help promote Sci-Fi & Fantasy SE?

Tags: discussion

Now that **Star Wars: The Complete Saga** is being released on Blu-Ray and getting mainstream attention, there will be zillions of fans old and new rediscovering these films and asking lots of questions. We already have a [solid *Star Wars* showing](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) on the site, but the more questions with great answers we have, the higher the chances are that new people will find our site during their quest to understand the ways of the Force. Science Fiction & Fantasy SE has a shot at having the best answers to those questions — better than any of those, you know, competitive sites. Essentially, this is a great time to recruit new members!

**What can you do to help?**

1. As you come across *Star Wars*-related articles/pictures/memes/etc., any questions that they inspire, no matter how silly, ask them here. This includes, but is definitely not limited to, questions regarding the Blu-Ray editions that you may have after its release on Friday. Also consider posting general questions about the original trilogies, any of the *Star Wars* animated movies or series, the expanded universe novels and comic books. You're not the only one having
   that question. Millions of other people will, too. Ask them even if
   you think you're going to be able to find the answer yourself… and
   if you do find the answer, go ahead and answer it yourself.
2. When answering these questions, do everything you can to overkill
   it. Don't just answer with a hyperlink to some other discussion
   group somewhere. Write a detailed, ultra-clear answer that is just
   as complete and clear as you can muster. Help us have the best
   possible answers to these common problems and questions fans have about the *Star Wars* universe!
3. If a question comes in that is unclear, badly written, badly
   formatted, or in bad English, edit it into shape. We've always
   encouraged edits that improve spelling, grammar, and clarity. Make
   every question count!

This is a great opportunity to build up a body of answers to common *Star Wars*-related questions that will be super-popular in the coming weeks as the Blu-Ray is released and people go ape over *Star Wars* again. These questions will bring in lots of traffic from search engines and if Science Fiction & Fantasy.SE continues to have great answers like we have had in the past, we stand a chance of attracting some great new users who will add value for years to come!

**Note:** *This tactic has been shamelessly adapted from [Joel's promotion to build new content for Apple SE](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/589/now-that-lion-is-out-help-promote-ask-different) and [Robert's to build Parenting](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239/now-that-school-is-in-session-are-your-school-age-questions-here). Let's show them we can do it too!*

Answer (score 2):

I made an effort under the [last](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5523/why-is-leia-a-princess) [few](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5556/why-some-jedi-disappear-when-they-die-while-others-dont) [days](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5574/why-did-luke-skywalker-call-obi-wan-ben) and I would like more participation form others; I would like to answer question too!

Comment: Much thanks, too! You've done a great job; I've enjoyed spending my morning at work reading Star Wars questions. What a weekend!

Comment: Well, others started to ask question too. So I was able to answer some. I think we got a momentum for Star Wars questions.

Comment: Seriously... 17 questions in the last week, at the time of my writing...