# Is anyone interested in a Walking Dead grant?

Tags: discussion, promotional-grant

The second season of AMC's ["The Walking Dead"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Walking_Dead_%28TV_series%29) starts on Sunday here in the US, and if the first season's popularity was an indicator, the second season will be huge. I think that this has almost as much potential to help get new eyes on the site [as the Star Wars grant](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/now-that-star-wars-is-coming-out-on-blu-ray-help-promote-sci-fi-fantasy-se) did.  I know there may be some trepidation about having more horror-leaning content on the site, but there is a precedence for [horror](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horror) and [zombie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zombie) questions. I think this is an area we could grow in a little bit, and also be ahead of the game in (there are already a ton of Star Wars questions on the internet, not so for Walking Dead).

I would like to send some of [the Walking Dead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Walking_Dead) comic book collected editions as well as the first season (either DVD or Blu-Ray) to a few users willing to generate content. I need to do this quickly, so I'd first like to make sure this is something that the site wants. Please let me know your thoughts in the next day and I will move forward based on that.

Comment: I think this is a great idea. Zombies are still very popular, and the Walking Dead is one of the best sci-fi shows on TV atm.  I haven't read the comic books yet, but they can only add to the body of subject matter for good questions/answers.

Comment: For once, I don't think I want to participate in this grant, lol... I can't do gore.

Answer (score 2):

Given the fact that I think most horror fans would very much like to see that content expanded here (and it's been made clear that works of speculative fiction in general are acceptable on this SE), I think this is a great idea.  This particular selection is great because it bridges two different types of media - you'll likely get both fans of the show and of the comic book involved in asking/answering.