# Who wants Walking Dead stuff?

Tags: discussion, promotional-grant

This is shockingly similar to the Star Wars Grant that happened last month (you can check that out [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/now-that-star-wars-is-coming-out-on-blu-ray-help-promote-sci-fi-fantasy-se); replace "Star Wars" with "Walking Dead"). The short version is:

> I want to give our interested users Walking Dead comics and
>   DVD/Blu-Rays to generate questions and content for the site. Then,
>   when people go online to look for Walking Dead content, they'll see
>   that *nothing tops SciFi.SE*.

The 5 highest-rep users who volunteer in an answer below will receive:

- [**Walking Dead: Book 1**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1582406197), which collects the first 12 issues of
  the series. If you are already an avid *Walking Dead* reader, we can amend this to only include collections you have not read yet, of comparable price.
- **Walking Dead: Season 1** on DVD/Blu-Ray (specify which; we
  will not provide a Blu-Ray player).

**In you answer/application, include what Walking Dead you have read (if any) and whether or not you prefer DVD or Blu-Ray.**

I want to get this stuff ordered and sent out in the next day to hopefully capitalize on Season 2's premiere on Sunday, so if you are interested you have until **Wednesday, October 12th, 1PM EST/17:00 UTC**.

Answer (score 1):

Alright. I'll go in for it. I'd prefer Blu-ray.

I have consumed none of the Walking Dead series. But I am a huge fan of Zombie flicks in general and will probably have some real insights/questions about it.

But subtract 4000 rep from me to give other people a shot ahead of me.

Comment: Any interest in writing something for the blog about this?  It can be short, and about anything related to Walking Dead that you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

I'd certainly be interested.  I haven't read any of the Walking Dead comics.  My preference would be for Blue Ray.

I'll be happy to rack my *braaaaaaaaains* for some good questions/answers (sorry, I couldn't resist!).

Comment: Any interest in writing something for the blog about this?  It can be short, and about anything related to Walking Dead that you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

I've got The Walking Dead Volume 1: Days Gone Bye and have watched the show, but would love anything after Days Gone Bye.  Not really interested in having the show (definitely think that should go to people who haven't seen it, ideally).

I'm particularly interested in how the show differs from the comic, especially leading into Season 2.

Comment: Any interest in writing something for the blog about this?  It can be short, and about anything related to Walking Dead that you'd like.

Comment: I've been brewing on where to do a "changes in the show's characters vs the comic" and didn't even think of the blog (sorry!) - seems like the perfect place.

Answer (score 1):

Have got all the trades up from *Days Gone By* to *No Way Out* (volume 14). Can't wait to see if they're bringing in The Governor for the TV series. Do you think it's Merle?

But why is Andrea looking much like her sister Amy now? That's a question that needs answering.

DVD.

Comment: Any interest in writing something for the blog about this?  It can be short, and about anything related to Walking Dead that you'd like.

Comment: Have an idea after watching one of the recent eps. Need to flesh it out to more than 140 characters though

Answer (score 0):

Congrats, all four of you will be receiving Walking Dead items!

I will be in touch with you shortly via e-mail to coordinate the delivery of your items. Hurrah!

Also, ***braaaiiiiins***